# How to find documentation ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to change background color of toolbar when develop ionic app then I found this working solution

```
.toolbar-background {
  background-color: color($colors, primary);
  border: none;
}
```

My question is that how do you guys know that toolbar has class .toolbar-background. How can I find which classes that toolbar, header or other components have?

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Toolbar/), it seems like what you're meant to do is set SASS variables, not target classes...  Though I may be wrong.

Comment: I cannot find toolbar-background there

Comment: Check [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/) page out - filtering by "background toolbar" seems to bring back the variables you're after.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Seeing as I accidentally answered your question, lemme write it up as an actual answer.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not super familiar with the framework, but from what I can see on the [documentation for the Toolbar](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Toolbar/), it looks like you're not meant to target classes, rather you should set SASS variables in your `_variables.scss` file.

To that end, [the list of ionic SASS variables](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/) seems to be a fantastic resource.  Filtering for "toolbar" brought up several SASS variables which seemed useful for your case, such as `$toolbar-background` and `$toolbar-border-color`.